# Keyboard not working in Ubuntu but working fine in BIOS

Tags: 16.04, drivers, 18.04, keyboard

I was using **Ubuntu 16.04** and one day suddenly the **keyboard stopped working**. But the keyboard is **working fine in BIOS**. But it doesn't work once the system is booted into the OS. I tried installing all pending updates on Ubuntu and even upgraded the system to 18.04, but no way.

For testing purpose, I plugged in a **wireless keyboard to my laptop and it is working fine in both BIOS and in OS**. Now I'm not able to decide whether my OS has the problem or the keyboard (some hardware issues?). Is there any good **keyboard drivers** to try? I'm using `HP-15` series laptop (I can update the model number later, if necessary).

Thanks.

---

PS: I'm fine with completely format the system and re-install Ubuntu, if it will solve the issue. Should I go with that option?

Comment: Did you find an answer elsewhere? I have the same issues, today it stopped working but the keyboard has no issues in the BIOS. When booting from a LIVE USB, same issues arise as from the default OS. 

I really can't wrap my head around this issue as it's not an update that caused it, a different kernel doesn't help either. 
I also tried all other obvious restarting solutions, but nothing helped.

Comment: @mxox I couldn't find a solution for my particular problem. I started using an external keyboard and it's working fine. After a couple of months, my laptop's original keyboard also started working fine. It came out of nowhere and I am happy. So my problem solved, but couldn't find the solution to my issue.

Comment: In the meantime, I also got it working! I had to reset my laptop BIOS 3 times in a row to default because it's severely bugged and didn't fully regain functionality until then. After restoring to default, all worked fine again. You would expect the BIOS not to be the most bug ridden thing on the planet, but oh well...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the exact right commands for that specific distro, but interesting path you could follow.
(you can figure out the right command by yourself through  tab completion and -h , I assume.)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174091/mouse-and-keyboard-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2355795

```
 sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

I'm gonna try the same once I get home. 
I'm encountering the same issue on Lubuntu 19.04.

Comment: Update: 
* I do not have an external keyboard, so I cannot log onto my personal Lubuntu session.
* I booted from live-usb: keyboard didn't work there either. 
* I do not have an external keyboard, hence I couldn't type the commands I wanted.

Reviewing:

+ my keyboard does not work on:
- Normal Lubuntu.
-  Live-usb Lubuntu.
- Advanced Lubuntu options > previous kernels.
- Advanced Lubuntu options -> recovery mode.

+ Keyboard works fine on:
- BIOS/UEFI.
- Windows. 

I'll format and reinstall Lubuntu. I'll install PuTty on my phone, so next time I won't encounter this problem.

Comment: The fact that the keyboard didn't work on live-usb and recovery mode left me surprised.

It worked fine in BIOS and Windows tho. Damn.

Comment: I found the solution to my issue. It was not related to Ubuntu (or Linux overall) but it was the buggy BIOS version which took 3 resets to finally get it to stock values. From then on, everything worked fine again.

Comment: Thanks for updating, mxox. 
My problem was due to this: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-IdeaPad-1xx-3xx-5xx-7xx/Keyboard-suddenly-malfunctioning-Touchpad-doesn-t-work-at-all/m-p/4461449#M70633



Basically it appears to be some factory production problem in some Lenovo laptops. 
I had to take out the battery, the keyboard started working magically again. 
Could I simply press two buttons and take the battery out? 
No. I had to disassemble the whole machine with a couple screwdriver, take most components out, finally re-assemble it together and it worked. 
Damn.