# HP laptop keyboard and mouse tracker pad not working after kernel update

Tags: kernel

After updating Ubuntu 20.04 kernel from 5.0.4.42 to 5.0.4.45 keyboard and mouse tracker pad not working on HP laptop - display shows login page
boot into 5.0.42 works fine

Comment: This seems to be going around affecting some Acers also.  Have not seen proper solution to it yet, only to go down kernel or use external keyboard if handy.

Comment: Interesting link concerning buggy bios on HP.  Do not know if would help your problem.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096358/keyboard-not-working-in-ubuntu-but-working-fine-in-bios?rq=1

Comment: Does seem to be a known bug in recent kernels.  Link.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271845/keyboard-on-hp-notebook-stops-working-under-kernel-5-4-0-45-generic